# spring-boot-starter randomly stops working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project that is using custom spring-boot-starter. The way I understand is that for every starter we have to create META-INF folder and add spring.factories file to it and then add AutoConfiguration class.

It was working fine. But all of a sudden it stopped working. Then I had to remove the META-INF folder again and add it back and then it started working again. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Actually I had to remove the whole src/main/resources source folder and add it again

Answer (score 0):

My bad but for people who might run into issues. If you are using maven to build your projects do remember to include **/*.factories in the your pom under build